# String indices must be integers, not string - retrieving value from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to retrieve a value from a dictionary. It works fine in one part of my code but then breaks in the next.

```
if user is not None:

    user["Username"] = "Temp-"+user["Username"]

    print "USER ID: " + str(user["ID"]) #Works fine
    #Rename user in source account
    patch_user(user, headers)
```

Patch User:

```
def patch_user( user, headers ):
    """Patch a User field based on their ID
    """
    patched_user = request('patch_user', user["AccountID"], user, headers)
```

Then in request:

```
def request( request, account_id, user, headers):
    """Send a User request to the server
    Send a request to the server
    """
    url = api_root + "/accounts/" + str(account_id)

    function_dictionary = {'get_user_from_id': (requests.get,                       #Function
                                               (url + "/users/" + str(user),),      #Tuple of Arguments
                                               {'headers': headers}),               #Dictionary of keyword args

                               'patch_user':(requests.patch,
                                             (url + "/users/" + str(user["ID"]),),
                                             {'headers': headers, 'data':json.dumps(user)})

    func, args, kwargs = function_dictionary[request]
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)

    #Throw exception if non-200 response
    result.raise_for_status()

    #Result from query
    print "Query " + request + " result: " + result.text

    return result
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

at `(url + "/users/" + str(user["ID"]),),`

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit**
Full Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.0\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 7
6, in exec_file
    exec(code_obj, global_variables)
  File "C:\Front-End\pcli-front
.py", line 179, in <module>
    user_operations.move_user(arguments['<source>'],arguments['<destination>'],
arguments['<id>'], headers)
  File "C:\Front-End\user_opera
tions.py", line 27, in move_user
    user = get_user_from_id(source_account, user_id, headers)
  File "C:\Front-End\user_opera
tions.py", line 68, in get_user_from_id
    user = request('get_user_from_id', account_id, user_id, headers)
  File "C:\Front-End\user_opera
tions.py", line 131, in request
    (url + "/users/" + str(user["ID"]),),
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Show us `patch_user` and the full exception traceback. You likely reused the `user` variable name when you were already using it for the function's first argument.

Comment: you have re-used user variable as string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception is coming from an entirely different code path than you think it is. `patch_user` has nothing to do with it; the stack trace shows that the problem is coming from `get_user_from_id`.

It looks like the third argument of `request` means something different when called from `patch_user` or `get_user_from_id`. When `patch_user` calls it, `user` is a dict. When `get_user_from_id` calls it, `user` is a string representing a user ID. The problem is that `request` still tries to build the full `function_dictionary` regardless of which type of request it's making, so this line:

```
(url + "/users/" + str(user["ID"]),),
```

still runs even when `user` is a string. To fix this, you could use an else/if chain instead of the dictionary to avoid running the problematic code when it shouldn't be run, or you could divide `request` into separate methods for each request type.

Comment: Yeah you're right, just noticed the same thing. It seems that `user["ID"]` in `patch_user` in `request`, is being evaluated even when the request is `get_user_from_id`...

Comment: @Tomcelic: Looks like you realized the problem while I was editing my answer. I hope the edit is useful anyway; I've suggested some ways to fix the bug.

Answer (score 2):

In `patch_user`, the variable `user` is a string and no longer a dictionary.

To see what is happening, you can try to add `print repr(user)` in several places in the code. Or use the logging module.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of Aaron Digulla:

I recommend to learn using Pythons debugger, which helps a lot, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html.

The way I use pdb is running a script with "%run" from IPython shell, and starting pdb in case of a crash with "%debug", see http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#debugging