# Extract dictionary containing variables from function

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a function that looks like this:

```
def request( request = None, account_id = 0, user_id = 0, user = {"ID":0}, headers = None):
    """Send a User request to the server
    Send a request to the server
    """
    url = api_root + "/accounts/" + str(account_id)

    function_dictionary = {'get_user_from_id': (requests.get,                       #Function
                                               (url + "/users/" + str(user_id),),      #Tuple of Arguments
                                               {'headers': headers}),               #Dictionary of keyword args

                               'get_user_from_username': (requests.get,
                                                (url + "/users?username=" + str(user_id),),
                                                {'headers': headers}),

                               'get_user_from_email': (requests.get,
                                             (url + "/users?email=" + str(user_id),),
                                             {'headers': headers}),

                               'delete': (requests.delete,
                                          (url + "/users/" + str(user_id),),
                                          {'headers': headers}),

                               'patch_user':(requests.patch,
                                             (url + "/users/" + str(user["ID"]),),
                                             {'headers': headers, 'data':json.dumps(user)}),

                               'post': (requests.post,
                                        (url + "/users" ,),
                                        {'headers': headers,'data':json.dumps(user)})
                               }

    func, args, kwargs = function_dictionary[request]
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)

    #Throw exception if non-200 response
    result.raise_for_status()

    #Result from query
    print "Query " + request + " result: " + result.text

    return result
```

Would it be possible to remove this dictionary from the `request` function so it is not re-built every-time a request is called?

The main problem being that - there are variables which need to be plugged in when the function is called i.e `user_id, user, account_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easily.

But I can't see what reason you would have for doing so. The overhead of constructing a six-item dictionary on every request is absolutely insignificant.

Comment: The problem is that the arguments to the function mean different things depending on the `request` argument, so building certain parts of the dictionary triggers an error when the arguments are of the wrong type. See the OP's [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158900/string-indices-must-be-integers-not-string-retrieving-value-from-dictionary) for some context.